# There is a list whose contents are type of vector<T>

Tags: c++, stl

What should I do to get any vector of the list?

I use following code to do it currently:

```
list<vector<T>> alist;

list<vector<T>>::iterator iter = alist.begin();

vector<T> vec(*iter);
```

is there any other way by which I don't need to copy the data?

Comment: Why does it have to be a vector? Why not simplify to a `list<int>` and ask how to get any integer out of the list?

Comment: I think it may more sample when I need to save something whose type is vector<T>.If I would like to get the data, I could get directly instead of getting single data and then package them into a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access all vector of list and modify individual values, you can write as descried below.

```
    for (auto& v : alist) {
        for (auto& i : v) {
            i = 13;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have can be written equivalently as:

```
vector<T> vec = alist.front();
```

Comment: maybe check for alist.empty() before invoking alist.front() ?

Comment: You are right, but i don't want to modify the list, I have to copy the old list for a new one, and then use: `new_list.front;`   `new_list.pop_front();` It may cost much space when the list is so large.